# Ignoring certain strings on second cycle

Tags: javascript, arrays, cycle

So, I have an array, which contains multiple strings.

```
var Array = ["mods/red1.png", "mods/red2.png", "mods/red3.png", "mods/orange1.png", "mods/orange2.png", "mods/orange3.png", "mods/blue1.png", "mods/blue2.png", "mods/blue3.png"];
```

My function picks one randomly. I need to set this up: if it picked up red1, it would ignore all strings with red, and would only print out one of the orange or blue.

Current code looks something like this:

```
var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * Array.length);
var num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * Array.length);
     if(RedModArray[num] !== undefined){
                document.mod1.src = Array[num];
if(Array[num].indexOf("red") > -1){
document.mod2.src = Array[num2];
}
```

But no matter what I've done, it either doesn't print out anything, or is still random.

`mod1` and `mod2` are the names of elements in html.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of notes for you;

You're only checking two values.  If Array[num] **and** Array[num2] both contain "red", then you're out of luck.

You're saving to two different locations.  Based on your explanation that it sometimes "doesn't print out anything", I'm going to guess that you're printing document.mod2.src, which will only be populated if Array[num] is red.

To solve these problems, you're going to need to use a `while` loop, and store your end result to a single location.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is exactly what your code does:
 * if "is not red" => print (is random)
 * if "is red" => dont print anything

I guess you would prefer to choose a fallback in case of "is red" like:
 * if "is red" => pick a different one

```
var a = ["mods/red1.png", "mods/red2.png", "mods/red3.png", "mods/orange1.png", "mods/orange2.png", "mods/orange3.png", "mods/blue1.png", "mods/blue2.png", "mods/blue3.png"];
var o1 = a[Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length)];
var o2;
do { o2 = a[Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length)]; }
while (o2.indexOf("red") >= 0);
```

Since random() chooses randomly, you might end up picking a red one over and over. Depending on your real use case there may not even be any valid elements left to pick from. So instead of the solution above i rather propose something like this: filter the elements you dont want after the first pick.

```
var o1 = a[Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length)];
a = a.filter(function(o) { return o.indexOf('red') < 0; })
var o2 = a[Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length)];
```

PS: dont name a variable "Array"!

Comment: You got it right what I meant, but i have 0 idea how I should implement the snippet into my current function. But I came up with an idea where i should make a Array for each color, randomly pick a array, and then pick one string from that array, if it makes sense.

Comment: i dont know your actual use case, so i cant really help. you can always use a second array if you cannot modify the one (replace "a = a.filter..." with "b = a.filter..." and then work with b).